# What kind of car is Sinbad driving?

Tags: houseguest

During the opening credits of Houseguest, Sinbad is driving a very small car.  What kind of car is it?

Comment: can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I'll see what I can get.

Comment: a 1977 bucket deluxe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the car below is the one, it is a 1968 Austin-Healey Sprite. Found using the Internet Movie Cars Database. If that is not the car you are looking for, they have a [list](http://www.imcdb.org/movie_110066-Houseguest.html) of all the cars seen in the movie.

[image]

Comment: Man, that is a p.o.s.!!!

Comment: TIL the IMCDB is a thing.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe There is also the Internet Movie Firearms Database, for help identifying which firearms are used in movies: http://www.imfdb.org